# Using JQuery to add anchor + href to dynamically generated html - cannot right click in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, right-click, dynamically-generated

I am writing a facebook-like chat appliation, and (as in facebook) at the top of each chatbox I have added a link that opens the associated user profile when clicked on. The html for the chatboxes is dynamically generated using javascript/jquery.

The problem is that in Firefox this link is not "right clickable". While in Chrome this link *is* right-clickable.

So, I have two questions 1) why is this href not right-clickable in Firefox. 2) Is there a *better* way that I should be adding dynamically generated href's to my code using javascript/jquery.

Currently, I am using (in pseudo code):

```
$('#chatbox_identifier').wrap("<a href=link_to_user_profile></a>") // set once
$('#chatbox_identifier').text("UserName/Status text")  // can be set many times
```

Note: the Username/Status text can change depending on if the user is Idle/Away/Online, and therefore will be reset every time a users online status changes. This is part of the reason why I have wrapped it in the anchor (since the anchor never changes - I am only updating what really needs to be modified).

"Bonus question": is there any reason why the following should not show up as a "clickable" hyperlink when dynamically generated (in pseudo-code):

```
$('#chatbox_identifier').html("<a href=link_to_user_profile>UserName/Status</a>")
```

This is the first approach that I wanted to take, but I could not get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: If you post a working example demonstrating your problem using http://jsfiddle.net/ you will have a much higher chance of getting a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the chatbox code (for which I am not the original author) had the following declaration:

```
uiChatboxTitlebar.find('*').add(uiChatboxTitlebar).disableSelection()
```

This resulted in preventing right-clicks in Firefox.

regards
Alex

Comment: hmm, didn't know about this method. You're it stops righclicking as well?

Comment: In my implementation, and in Firefox (not in Chrome), the above code disabled right-clicking. I have verified that removing that declaration re-enabled right-clicking.